# How to append or add 3rd Node to the Kendo treeview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I want to add another node to the kendotreeview but that would be dynamic unlike the other two being static/Hardcoded.
Here is the code for it:

```
var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  data: [{
    text: "Furniture",
    items: [{
      text: "Tables & Chairs"
    }, {
      text: "Sofas"
    }, {
      text: "Occasional Furniture"
    }]
  }, {
    text: "Decor",
    items: [{
      text: "Bed Linen"
    }, {
      text: "Curtains & Blinds"
    }, {
      text: "Carpets"
    }]
  }]
});
var treeview = $("#treeview-left").data("kendoTreeView");
treeview.add(new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: ResolveUrl("/Analysis/GetData/"),
      dataType: "jsonp",
    }
  },
}));
$("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: inlineDefault
});
```

How I can proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a API example that shows how to add nodes to the TreeView.

[Kendo TreeView API](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/api)